# Propane fireplace won’t light

Tags: fireplace, propane

I have a propane fireplace I haven’t used in about 2 years. We just had the propane tanks filled, the valves on the tank are open. Also the valve on propane line coming into the house is in the on position. The pilot ignition sparks however I don’t smell propane and the pilot will not light. Any thoughts or suggestions?

I live in Pennsylvania so weather has been cold, but I also tried starting it in the fall before cold hit with no luck. Nothing else hooked up, just fireplace.

Comment: How cold has it been? Anything else hooked up to the propane? Possible water in line leading to an ice plug?

Comment: When you turn on the fireplace, can you hear gas flowing? Appreciate this may be different for different types of fireplace but in the UK when lighting a gas fireplace you can hear gas flowing through the burners when you first switch it on (but before you light it. I wouldn't recommend attempting to listen to the burners on a lit fireplace!)

Comment: Is there a propane on/off valve on the fireplace itself?

Answer (score 17):

If you haven't used it for two years, the line is probably full of air that needs to be flushed out to get gas to the appliance.

When you tried it in the fall and it didn't work, that would have been a good time to call your propane service provider for assistance.

Not having done so, now is also a good time to do that. I hesitate to suggest DIY creative approaches with fuel gas appliances. The risks are too high.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't hear gas flowing have you overlooked an additional control that is needed to allow gas to flow until a temperature sensor on a pilot light or similar allows it to stay on?

For example, see the steps at [Family Handyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-light-a-gas-fireplace/) which are different for a fire with a pilot light.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work in the RV (Recreational Vehicle) business. SPIDER WEBS! Spiders attracted to propane line/burner assembly. You need to turn gas off, find where the gas line to burner assembly is, and clear that out-pipe cleaner? We  would deal with this often.